# How do I enable Code Coverage for .NET Standard Library (2.0) project in VSTS (CI)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Please help me - How do I enable/show code coverage result for .NET Standard library project (2.0) in VSTS (CI). Have enable Test result through **dotnet Test task** (.NET Core 2.0 preview) and able to to see the passed Test cases. Next step I have added "publish result" task but it's showing the below warning during Build -
***No test result files matching _temp**/*.trx were found***.
Even I have modified the .csproj file and added `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>`.

Using Visual Studio 2017 Professional (version - 15.5.2) 
Project - .NET Standard Library (2.0)
Unit Test - MSTest (inbuilt in Visual Studio)

What tasks / how tasks should I need to add/modify in Build Definition in VSTS, so that I can see Code Coverage against Unit Testing.

Tasks for Code Coverage -
[TestAssemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3o5m.png)

[other option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KnSq.png)

Now I am able to see the Code Coverage (not sure whether correct code coverage is showing or not) but the tasks - Test Assemblies ***.test*.dll is failing with the below error -
[Code-Coverage-Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Iq1.png)

- No test is available in .........$(BuildConfiguration)\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

  - No test is available in ...... $(BuildConfiguration)\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Thanks.

Regards,
Deb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you can get code coverage result through Visual Studio. As far as I know, Enterprise version is required (You can use Hosted VS 2017 agent).

The Code Coverage for .Net Core Unit test project:

1. Add `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` to PreopertyGroup

Sample:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

2. Install [Microsoft.CodeCoverage package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeCoverage/) to test project

Secondly, you can run test through Visual Studio Test task: (

Path to vstest.console.exe: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe`

Check `Code coverage enabled` option

Other console options: `/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0"`)

[image]

Comment: Hi starian, First of all I am using VS Professional ver. 15.5.2. not using Enterprise Edition. Completed the Point No 1 and Point 2 as you stated above. Please  help me How do I get code coverage result in VSTS; i.e. which tasks do I need to add in Build Definition that will show / support the code coverage after build completion in VSTS (CI) for .NET Standard Library (version 2.0) project. Thanks. Deb

Comment: Can you get code coverage result through Visual Studio? Based on this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/), just Enterprise version supports Code coverage). Using Visual Studio Test task (Check second point of my answer)

Comment: I am using VS professional, so unable to do code coverage locally. Secondly I have followed what you have mentioned, unable to find vstest.console.exe as I am using vs professional. So I want to enable code coverage in VSTS (VisualStudio.com --> Build --> Build Definition). Please tell me which tasks should I need to add in Build Definition to get the Code coverage for .NET Standard Library 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: @DebasisGhosh It is Visual Studio Test Task, check the screenshot in my answer. Also you need to use Hosted VS 2017 agent.

Comment: thank for your help. Now i am getting the below errors, though i have installed the prerequisite packages and all unit test are passed in local VS 2017. Test Assemblies **\*.test*.dll -
Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: Failed to launch CodeCoverage.exe. No code coverage will be collected..
No test is available in ..\release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate and try again. Thanks - Deb

Comment: though I have added <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" /> into the project. Not sure which pacakges I need to install again. Thanks. Deb

Comment: @DebasisGhosh specify `**\*Test*.dll
!**\*TestAdapter*.dll
!**\obj\**` (three lines) in Test assemblies box of Visual Studio Test task to exclude necessary dll files (e.g. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform‌​.MSTestAdapter.Platf‌​ormServices.Interfac‌​e.dll).

Comment: already added three lines in Test assemblies, though I am getting the same issue. Please check - uploaded the tasks screenshot in  Tasks for Code Coverage - TestAssemblies

Comment: Replace `!**\*TestAdapter.dll` to `!**\*TestAdapter*.dll`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your help and support. Now build got succeeded. Excluded these files - !**\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll
!**\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll. Will try - !**\*TestAdapter*.dll. Thanks - Deb